# Installing Hyper-V Integration Components on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hyper-v, ubuntu-9.04

Some big news this week was Microsoft released the [Hyper-V integration components for Linux source code under the GPL v2](http://port25.technet.com/archive/2009/07/20/the-hyper-v-linux-integration-components.aspx).

I just installed Ubuntu Server 9.04 in a Hyper-V VM with a Legacy Network Adapter.  How do I install the integration components?  Do I have to wait until they are included in the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either wait for a distro-integrated kernel to include it, wait for someone in the community to build an appropriate kernel package (which probably won't take too long), or patch and build a kernel yourself.  Unless you're familiar with the procedures for building a kernel and applying kernel patches (given that there'll likely be significant changes between the Ubuntu-released kernel and the bleeding edge kernel these patches are targeted at), I'd leave it alone and wait for someone else to do it.  It won't be a trivial operation.

Comment: almost exactly as I would have put it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in answer to another post on ServerFault (cross reference [Ubuntu 10.04 Server on Hyper-V Server R2 has sluggish install and command line](https://serverfault.com/questions/138110/ubuntu-10-04-server-on-hyper-v-server-r2-has-sluggish-install-and-command-line)):

http://blog.allanglesit.com/Blog/tabid/66/EntryId/53/Hyper-V-Guests-Ubuntu-10-04-Alpha-3-Synthetic-Devices.aspx

In summary, the integration components are already part of the 2.6.32 Linux Kernel, at least in Ubuntu 10.04.  Quoting:

> Add the following to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
>
> > hv_vmbus
> >
> > hv_storvsc
> >
> > hv_blkvsc
> >
> > hv_netvsc
>
> Generate a new initrd image
>
> > update-initramfs –u
>
> make sure /etc/network/interfaces is
>   pointed at the synthetic network
>   adapter
>
> > auto seth0
> >
> > iface seth0 inet dhcp

It worked well for me to get the synthetic network adapter working with an Ubuntu 10.04 Server 64 bit guest operating system.