# ubuntu install on hyper-v

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I just installed latest ubuntu server edition on hyper-v r2. Install went good but i get no network connectivity.

I have a legacy network connection setup in hyper-v for that vm.

I setup static ip for that vm(everything looks good in interfaces file)

Nothing out of ordinary in ifconfig

but it is not connecting to anything?

Is there anything i am missing here?

Getting following error when start vm, looks some what related, no idea what it is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, **Jeremy Hajek** reminded me of the reason, thanks!
Funny part is, I had this problem only when I enabled more then one CPU in Hper-V Manager.

Udev sets the device name in newer versions of Ubuntu. Issuing 'ifconfig -a', you'll see all network interfaces, whether they are configured or not. I noticed that when I added the (standard) network adapter, I forgot to disable the "legacy" network adaptor. For both I had set the same MAC address, this is what might have confused my config.

So:

- make sure you only have one network adapter configured in Hyper-V Manager
- configure eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces
- delete /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (it will be re-generated on boot) so your only interface will *really* be called eth0
- if you want to use all hyper-v modules at boot, append to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

> hv_vmbus
>
> hv_blkvsc
>
> hv_netvsc
>
> hv_storvsc

(ignore blank lines)

- rebuild initramfs: 'update-initramfs -u'

You should be done now, not addressing the smbios issue though. Does anyone know the full resulting kernel parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this using vmware but worth a try as I think it is a Ubuntu response.

Possibly your network card information needs to be "bumped." 
Use your favorite editor to edit this file `/etc/network/interfaces` 
 edit the file where it says eth0--try to change it to say eth1
then reset networking `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`  and it should catch.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 should support running on a Hyper-V host with little to no trouble but you need to [load the modules](http://blog.allanglesit.com/Blog/tabid/66/EntryId/53/Hyper-V-Guests-Ubuntu-10-04-Alpha-3-Synthetic-Devices.aspx) supporting synthetic devices and reconfigure networking accordingly.

Earlier versions or any Linux for that matter likely wants you to install the Hyper-V Linux Integration Services, though I have no idea if that's still required with the newer versions of the Linux kernel.

Also see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/138110/ubuntu-10-04-server-on-hyper-v-server-r2-has-sluggish-install-and-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the network device Hyper-V exposes to the guest is supported on Ubuntu?

Does `ls /sys/class/net/` list any devices but `lo`?